# Boxshadow and spacing wtih CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css

I am having 3 issues across two pages:

1. http://www.easythemepro.com/ - The button at the bottom of the text appears to have quite a bit of space between the text and the button.  What code is adding in this extra spacing?
2. http://www.easythemepro.com/ - The boxshadowing on the page appears to stop right after the button.  What do I need to do to make it extend around the entire page?
3. [http://www.easythemepro.com/themes.php](http://www.easythemepro.com/) - I'm having the same problem with boxshadowing on this page as well, but it is extending a bit further.  What needs to be changed to make it extend all the way down?

I've been staring at the same code all day and can't seem to figure out what's happening with these last 3 issues.  I know it's problem simple stuff I'm overlooking after having stared at it all for so long...

Comment: Once the **links** will be **no longer available**, this **question** and it's answers will have **no value** to anyone. Please while asking questions think also on future generations. The markup allows you to attach images, and cause we like to see some code, add that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)

In your CSS (style.css) on line 201. You have the following rule:

```
bottom: 0;
```

Remove this rule.

Setting the position of the button to "bottom: 0;", puts it at the bottom of the parent container. In this case you do not want this.

2)

Set the height of body & html to 100%:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
```

Setting the height of body & html to 100% makes them fill 100% of the height as you'd expect!

3)

Inside #wpwrap set your overflow to automatic.

```
overflow: auto;
```

This will make sure the contents of #wpwrap do not escape.

Comment: That fixed everything except #1.  On the themes page it's not showing an additional scrollbar in my browser...

Comment: Take "overflow: auto" off of #wpwrap and stick it under body.